# How to run a winforms Form window concurrently within a script

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to run a System.windows.form object alongside with my main script.
For example, I want to run a PowerShell script which has a loop and never stops. I wish to be able to terminate the execution using a button on a WPF Form object.

I have tried the method form.show(), but it doesn't give me control.

```
clear host
Function hey(){
    # code to exit, or do what I want it to do.
}
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(1024,768)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 15)
$btn.add_click({$(hey)})
$btn.Text = "Click here"
$form.Controls.Add($btn)


while($true){
    write-host "int = $int."
    start-sleep 3
    $int = $int + 1
    $drc = $form.ShowDialog()
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I am trying to run a `WPF System.windows.form`... - you have no idea what you're talking about, do you?

Comment: Not too much. I saw somewhere that this belongs to the WPF scheme. But anyway I am talking about a System.windows.form object.

Comment: I Removed the WPF tag from your question. This has nothing to do with WPF at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the "Click Here" button close the form and exit the while loop, you can do something like this:

```
Function hey(){
    $form.Close()
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(1024,768)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 15)
$btn.add_click({$(hey)})
$btn.Text = "Click here"
$form.Controls.Add($btn)

while ($true) {
    write-host "int = $int."
    start-sleep 3
    $int = $int + 1
    $drc = $form.ShowDialog()
    if ($drc = "Cancel") { break }
}
```

Comment: The flow of the script is that it reaches $form.ShowDialog(), and hangs there. I want the codes after that function call to be executed even if the form is not closed. Is that possible? It is like in Win8, when you stream some video, and also have calculator open to do stuff, and the video also keeps going.